# Show that there exists some constant $c > 0$ such that $f(x) > g(x) + c$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, with $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Show that there exists some constant $c > 0$ such that $f(x) > g(x) + c$

I need to show there is a gap between the two graphs. Is the idea to show that for every point in g(x), there is always an f(x) > g(x)?

Comment: Hint: $h(x)=f(x)-g(x) \gt 0$ must have a minimum on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $[a,b]$ is compact, the continuous map $x\mapsto f(x)-g(x)$ attains a minimum. Let $$c = \frac12\min\{f(x)-g(x):x\in[a,b]\},$$ then $f(x)>g(x)+c$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ as desired.

Comment: @DaanMichiels Indeed.

Comment: Of course you mean $[a,b]$ instead of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam When I think "closed interval" it is $[0,1]$ that comes to mind :)

Comment: What about my answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that

$\forall c>0 \exists x\in [a,b]  : f(x)\leq g(x)+c$

OR ( if we take special $c$)

$\forall n \in \mathbb N \; \exists x_n\in [a,b]: \; f(x_n)\leq g(x_n)+\frac{1}{n+1}$

$(x_n)$ is a sequence of the compact $[a,b]$.

it has a convergent subsequence $(y_n)$.

let $L$ be its limit which is always in the closed $[a,b]$.

thus we have

$\forall n \in  \mathbb N  f(y_n)\leq g(y_n)+\frac{1}{n+1}$

when $n$ goes to $+\infty$

we get by continuity,

$f(L)\leq g(L)$

and the contradiction with the hypotheses.